# Android: Android Build failed with an exception: error: attribute tagetAlpha y error: attribute depensOn

Tags: android

Buen día comunidad, soy algo nuevo en Android

Verán al ejecutar la aplicación me sale el siguiente error

> "AAPT: error: attribute depensOn not found"
>   "AAPT: error: attribute tagetAlpha not found".

Estoy tratando de utilizar un comportamiento dependiente o de vista simple, [Comportamiento de vista simple para Android CoordinatorLayout .](https://github.com/zoonooz/simple-view-behavior)

Primero agregue la dependencia tal cual explica, aca esta mi archivo de dependencias de Gradle.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

//LIBRERIA PARA BOTTOM BAR
implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'

//LIBRERIA PARA IMAGEN REDONDA
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'

//LIBRERIA PARA IMAGEN DE INTERNET
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

//LIBRERIA COMPORTAMIENTO DEPENDIENTE
implementation 'com.zoonref:simple-view-behavior:1.0' }
```

Según el usó de este comportamiento, puede configurar el efecto utilizando solo la opción xml.

- 1. Establecer el comportamiento del diseño para esta clase de biblioteca **app:layout_behavior="com.zoonref.SimpleViewBehavior"**. (*Justamente lo que hago en mi CircleImageView y TextView.*)
- 2. Establecer la vista de dependencia especificando id de recurso por **app:dependsOn="@+id/{your view id}"**.
- 3. Establecer el tipo de dependencia **app:dependType="{x,y,width,height}"**.
- 4. Establecer el valor objetivo de la vista de dependencia según el tipo que elija **app:dependTargetXXX="{value}"**.
- 5. Y por ultimo, establecer la apariencia de destino que desea que su vista anime.

Justamente lo que estoy haciendo.

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_circleimageprofile"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_circleimageprofile"
    android:src="@drawable/image2"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop_circleimageprofile"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_circleimageprofile"
    app:layout_behavior="com.zoonref.SimpleViewBehavior"
    app:depensOn="@+id/appBarProfile"
    app:dependType="y"
    app:dependTargetY="@dimen/limitY_circleimage"
    app:targetX="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:targetY="@dimen/margintoptoolbar_circleimageprofile"
    app:targetWidth="@dimen/width_circleimagetoolbar"
    app:targetHeight="@dimen/width_circleimagetoolbar" />

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/usernameToolbarProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="281dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginleft_usernametoolbarprofile"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop_usernametoolbarprofile"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_circleimageprofile"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/username_card"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_usernametoolbarprofile"
    app:layout_behavior="com.zoonref.SimpleViewBehavior"
    app:depensOn="@+id/appBarProfile"
    app:dependType="y"
    app:dependTargetY="@dimen/limitY_appcompattext_usernametoolbarprofile"
  app:targetY="@dimen/margintoptargety_appcompattext_usernametoolbarprofile"
    app:tagetAlpha="1" />
```

Pero al momento de correr el programa me sale el siguiente error:

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml","position":{"startLine":70}}],"original":"C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:71: AAPT: error: attribute depensOn (aka platzi.com:depensOn) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml","position":{"startLine":101}}],"original":"C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:102: AAPT: error: attribute depensOn (aka platzi.com:depensOn) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml","position":{"startLine":101}}],"original":"C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:102: AAPT: error: attribute tagetAlpha (aka platzi.com:tagetAlpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   Android resource linking failed
>   C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:71: AAPT: error: attribute depensOn (aka platzi.com:depensOn) not found.
>   C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:102: AAPT: error: attribute depensOn (aka platzi.com:depensOn) not found.
>   C:\Users\sebas\AndroidStudioProjects\PlatzigramSena\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:102: AAPT: error: attribute tagetAlpha (aka platzi.com:tagetAlpha) not found.

Esto es todo mi archivo xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="view.fragment.ProfileFragment"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarProfile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="200dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usernameProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/username_card"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_usernameprofile"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/pictureProfileRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


<!-- IMAGEN EN CIRCULO, LIBRERIA EN GRADLE -->
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_circleimageprofile"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_circleimageprofile"
    android:src="@drawable/image2"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop_circleimageprofile"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_circleimageprofile"
    app:layout_behavior="com.zoonref.SimpleViewBehavior"
    app:depensOn="@+id/appBarProfile"
    app:dependType="y"
    app:dependTargetY="@dimen/limitY_circleimage"
    app:targetX="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:targetY="@dimen/margintoptoolbar_circleimageprofile"
    app:targetWidth="@dimen/width_circleimagetoolbar"
    app:targetHeight="@dimen/width_circleimagetoolbar" />
    <!-- android:elevation TENDRA QUE EVR CON LA ANIMACION QUE VAYA TENER LA IMAGEN-->
    <!-- app:layout_behavior EL COMPORTAMIENTO QUE QUEREMOS DARLE-->
    <!--
        pp:depensOn="@+id/appBarProfile"  -> ESTA IMAGEN ESTA DEPENDIENDO DE "@+id/appBarProfile"
        app:dependType="y"                -> TYPO DE DEPENDENCIA, EN QUE SENTIDO VA TENER DEPENDENCIA
        app:dependTargetY="-256dp"        -> LIMITE HASTA DODNE QUEREMOS QUE SE MUEVA LA IMAGEN, QUE SUBA LA IMAGEN
        app:targetX="16dp"                -> UNA VEZ QUE LA IMAGEN SE POSICIONO, CUANDO MARGEN QUEREMOS DEJAR
        app:targetY="-16dp"               -> CUANTO QUEREMOS QUE SUBA
        app:targetWidth="40dp"            -> DE QUE DIMENSION VA QUEDAR LA IMAGEN
    -->



<!-- TextView QUE DEPENDE DE LA IMAGEN, QUEDA AL LADO DE LA IMAGEN -->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/usernameToolbarProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="281dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginleft_usernametoolbarprofile"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop_usernametoolbarprofile"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_circleimageprofile"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/username_card"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_usernametoolbarprofile"
    app:layout_behavior="com.zoonref.SimpleViewBehavior"
    app:depensOn="@+id/appBarProfile"
    app:dependType="y"
    app:dependTargetY="@dimen/limitY_appcompattext_usernametoolbarprofile"
    app:targetY="@dimen/margintoptargety_appcompattext_usernametoolbarprofile"
    app:tagetAlpha="1" /><!--CANTIDAD DE TRANSPARENCIA QUE QUEREMOS EN NUETSROS ELEMENTOS-->
```

Cualquier ayuda es muy apreciada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver el tu archivo de error que tienes lo siguiente:

attribute **depensOn** (aka platzi.com:depensOn) **not found.**

attribute **tagetAlpha** (aka platzi.com:tagetAlpha) **not found.**

Porque estos atributos no existen, es un error tipo grafico, corrigue a app:dependsOn y app:targetAlpha respectivamente.

Comment: Gracias pro tu aporte.  se que ese es el error, pero, según la documentación https://github.com/zoonooz/simple-view-behavior  Esta bien, queria saber si alguien la ha utilizado, le paso lo mismo y lo resolvió.  Viste la documentación?

Comment: Correguiste el error tipo grafico? app:dependsO en ves de depensOn? Qué comportamiento esperas obtener?

Comment: No amigo aun no, quisiera tener este comportamiento https://github.com/zoonooz/simple-view-behavior